C# specify kind on date
I am trying to work on getting data based on start and end date but I keep getting an error each time, this is what I have
var startDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(StartDate.Value.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue), DateTimeKind.Utc);
var endDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(EndDate.Value.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue), DateTimeKind.Utc);


This code looks OK, what error are you getting?

Welcome to Stack Overflow Stephen, before you move on, please read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times.

var startDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(StartDate.Value.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue), DateTimeKind.Utc);

var endDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(EndDate.Value.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue), DateTimeKind.Utc);
endDateTime = endDateTime.AddDays(1);

Remember to add this
endDateTime = endDateTime.AddDays(1);
